# different answers to uniform probability on a disk question

Tags: uniform-distribution

[image]

why are the answers to a. and to b. different?

There is .25 probability that a point will be within r/2 of the center, just by calculating the ratio of the areas of the two circles. Why is .25 not also the answer to b? The two questions appear to me to be asking the same thing, but apparently that is not the case. Can someone help me see the difference?

Comment: I see that the calculation of b. results in the answer (1/pi); but I don't see what is essentially different between question a. and question b.

Comment: Hint: the ratio of the area of the small circle to the area of the large circle is $\frac 14$. The ratio of the area of the square of side $r$ to the area of the large circle is??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers are different because the boundary of the region in (a) is a circle but the boundary of the region in (b) is a square:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Region in (a)} & & & \mathscr{A} = \{ (x,y) | \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leqslant r/2 \}, \\[6pt]
\text{Region in (b)} & & & \quad \ \ \mathscr{B} = \{ (x,y) | |x| \leqslant r/2, |y| \leqslant r/2 \}, \\[6pt]
\end{matrix}$$